# SonataAdminBundle sonata_type_model without delete button

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am trying to map a ManyToOne relationship product-category, and I use the sonata_type_model type to map the category entity when creating a product entity. The mapping and the default add button work fine.

From the documentation however, it seems that a delete button is also available, in addition to the default add button, when dealing with sonata_type_model ( from doc. 'btn_add, btn_list, btn_delete and btn_catalogue:'). However passing as an option 'btn_delete'=>true has no effect.

Thinking about it, it makes sense to allow also delete and edit functionalities, together with contextual "on the fly" addition of the related -toOne entity. Otherwise it is necessary to build a separated, dedicated admin block, making the 'add' functionality quite useless. Are such delete and edit functions available?

N.B I'm working with last stable release of Sonata Admin 2.3.3

Comment: Same questionning right now, can't make this 'btn_catalogue' work, it's pretty annoying